# translation of an idea in QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to bring your attention regarding a detail which might be ridiculous for advanced people in Qt" but not for newbies as me.

I would like to connect a pushButton to a signal/slot while the user didn't press on a specified pushButton B:

What I want to do is:

```
do
{
        QObject::connect(pushButton_image, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(image()))
}
while (// THE USER DIDN'T PRESS THE PUSHBUTTON B ...)
```

As soon as the user press the PUSHBUTTON B, I want to disconnect pushButton_image with its previous signal / slot.

Thanks!

Comment: You're right. That does look ridiculous. Never use a loop to wait for user actions. It won't work. Connect to the signal that notifies of the event you're interested in, and do whatever action you desire in the slot.

Comment: -1 I know you say that you're a newbie, but this shows such a profound lack of understanding of signals and slots, that you can't have even read the documentation for it: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @cmannett85 This is too kind of you, let you be the best ever in signals / slots and let me be the 0 skill guy in Qt. And then? Will that resolve a big issue in the world? Bravo for such a good behaviour.

Comment: @user2354422 It takes time and effort to answer questions on SO, all we ask in return is that you put in the same effort in researching your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179003/stack-exchange-is-too-harsh-to-new-usersplease-help-them-improve-low-quality-po

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect it once, out of that while.

That's wrong because:
You can connect a slot to a signal multiple times. But it will be called s many times as you connected it.

You won't get out of that while loop.

A slot is connected as long as it gets disconnected. Being connected Its more like an state that an active task.

To disconnect you use

```
QObject::disconnect
```

In slot call

```
QObject::disconnect(pushButton_image, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(image()))
```

Done

Comment: You can vote up or/and accept if you liked it :-P

Comment: I wish I can, people are always downing my questions, and thus I don't have enough reputations to vote! Really sorry